# SIGSEGV during PyObject dealloc Python C API

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, segmentation-fault

I am trying to implement a simple generator using the Python C API. The generator functionality is working but the python interpreter (or something) segfaults during the call to `Py_TYPE(self)->tp_free((PyObject*)self)` I have read and reread the reference docs, and think I have the reference counting correct, but still the SIGSEGV remains. I've built the extension with debug symbols, and debugged with gdb (output below), and it seems it is happening inside the interpreter. Only thing I know that I haven't tried is building python from source with debug symbols, to allow further introspection. Any help or a point to the right documentation would appreciated. I'm using Python 3.6.4

```
#include "hexc.h"

// Define class boilerplate functions
static PyObject *hex_range_iter_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    hexrangeiter_t *self;

    self = (hexrangeiter_t *)(type->tp_alloc(type, 0));
    if (self != NULL) {
        self->pos = 0;
        self->dir = 0;
        self->distance = 1;
        self->radius = 0;
        self->hex = NULL;
        self->center = NULL;
    }

    return (PyObject *)self;
}

static void hex_range_iter_dealloc(hexrangeiter_t *self)
{
    Py_DECREF(self->hex);  // decref our stored hex
    Py_DECREF(self->center); // and our center point
    Py_TYPE(self)->tp_free((PyObject*)self); // SIGSEGV here

}

static int hex_range_iter_init(hexrangeiter_t *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    // Takes 2 args, the center of the ring as an AbstractHex, and the radius as an int
    static char *kwlist[] = {"center", "radius", NULL};
    if (! PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwds, "Oi", kwlist, &self->center, &self->radius))
        return -1;

    Py_INCREF(self->center); //increc\f here because Py_Arg_Parse... returns borrowed references
    PyObject *radius = PyLong_FromLong(1L);
    PyObject *direction = PyObject_CallMethod(self->center, "direction", "i", 4);
    PyObject *scaled = PyNumber_Multiply(direction, radius);
    self->hex = PyNumber_Add(self->center, scaled); // No incref needed because Py_Number_Add returns a new reference
    Py_DECREF(radius); // decref all of our temp variables
    Py_DECREF(direction);
    Py_DECREF(scaled);
    return 0;
}

static PyObject *hex_range_iter_next(hexrangeiter_t *self)
{

    self->pos++; // pos is the index along a side of a hexagonal ring
    if (self->pos >= self->radius)  // its length is equal to the radius of the ring
    {                               // so check if we've run off the end and if so change direction
        self->pos = 0;
        self->dir++;
    }

    if (self->dir >= 6)             // If we've already done all 6 sides
    {
        self->dir = 0;              // reset our direction
        self->distance++;           // and increase our radius

        if (self->distance >= self->radius) // If we've reached our max radius
            return NULL;                    // return NULL to exit generator
                                            // Returning NULL in this case is enough. The next() builtin will raise the
                                            // StopIteration error for us.

        PyObject *radius = PyLong_FromLong(self->distance); // calculate our new starting position  v
        PyObject *direction = PyObject_CallMethod(self->center, "direction", "i", 4);
        PyObject *scaled = PyNumber_Multiply(direction, radius); 
        Py_DECREF(self->hex); // make sure to decref our unused hex from last call
        self->hex = PyNumber_Add(self->center, scaled);  // finish calc and save new hex            ^
        Py_DECREF(radius);  // decref all our temp variables
        Py_DECREF(direction);
        Py_DECREF(scaled);
    }

    PyObject *ret = self->hex; // grab a ref to our return value
    self->hex = PyObject_CallMethod(ret, "neighbor", "i", self->dir); // store the next hex in our sequence

    return (ret);
}

PyTypeObject HexRangeGenType = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type, 0)
    "HexRangeGenerator",             /* tp_name */
    sizeof(hexrangeiter_t),           /* tp_basicsize */
    0,                              /* tp_itemsize */
    (destructor)hex_range_iter_dealloc,  /* tp_dealloc */
    0,                              /* tp_print */
    0,                              /* tp_getattr */
    0,                              /* tp_setattr */
    0,                              /* tp_reserved */
    0,                 /* tp_repr */
    0,                              /* tp_as_number */
    0,                              /* tp_as_sequence */
    0,                              /* tp_as_mapping */
    0,                              /* tp_hash */
    0,                              /* tp_call */
    0,                              /* tp_str */
    0,                              /* tp_getattro */
    0,                              /* tp_setattro */
    0,                              /* tp_as_buffer */
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT,             /* tp_flags */
    0,                              /* tp_doc */
    0,                              /* tp_traverse */
    0,                              /* tp_clear */
    0,                              /* tp_richcompare */
    0,                              /* tp_weaklistoffset */
    PyObject_SelfIter,              /* tp_iter */
    (iternextfunc)hex_range_iter_next,   /* tp_iternext */
    0,                              /* tp_methods */
    0,                              /* tp_members */
    0,                              /* tp_getset */
    0,                              /* tp_base */
    0,                              /* tp_dict */
    0,                              /* tp_descr_get */
    0,                              /* tp_descr_set */
    0,                              /* tp_dictoffset */
    (initproc)hex_range_iter_init,                 /* tp_init */
    0,            /* tp_alloc */
    hex_range_iter_new,                  /* tp_new */
};
```

hex.c

```
#ifndef HEXC_H
#define HEXC_H

#include <Python.h>
#include <structmember.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// #include "math_3d.h"

// declare Hex object structure
struct abstracthex_s;
struct hex_s;
struct slice_s;
struct stack_s;
struct grid_s;

struct hexringiter_s;
struct hexrangeiter_s;

typedef struct abstracthex_s    abstracthex_t;
typedef struct slice_s          slice_t;
typedef struct stack_s          stack_t;
typedef struct hex_s            hex_t;
typedef struct grid_s           grid_t;

typedef struct hexringiter_s    hexringiter_t;
typedef struct hexrangeiter_s   hexrangeiter_t;

struct abstracthex_s
{
    PyObject_HEAD
    int q;
    int r;
    int s;
};

struct hexringiter_s
{
    PyObject_HEAD
    int pos;
    int dir;
    int radius;
    PyObject *hex;
};

struct hexrangeiter_s
{
    PyObject_HEAD
    int dir;
    long pos;
    long distance;
    long radius;
    PyObject *hex;
    PyObject *center;
};

// declare Python type objects
extern PyTypeObject AbstractHexType;
extern PyTypeObject HexRingGenType;
extern PyTypeObject HexRangeGenType;
extern PyTypeObject HexType;
extern PyTypeObject SliceType;
extern PyTypeObject StackType;
extern PyTypeObject GridType;

// declare some handy constants
static int  DIRECTIONS[6][3] = {
    {1, 0, -1},
    {1, -1, 0},
    {0, -1, 1},
    {-1, 0, 1},
    {-1, 1, 0},
    {0, 1, -1}
};

#endif
```

test.py

```
import hexc
import time

center = hexc.AbstractHex(0,0,0)

start = time.time()
z = 0
for hex in hexc.HexRangeGenerator(center, 5):
    z += 1
print(time.time() - start)
```

gdb stack trace

```
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ffff67ce521 in hex_range_iter_dealloc (self=0x7ffff6a0f5f0) at hexc/hex_range_iter.c:28
#2  0x00007ffff73c2e05 in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () from /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
#3  0x00007ffff742b2c8 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx () from /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
#4  0x00007ffff73be6ec in PyEval_EvalCode () from /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
#5  0x00007ffff7490f84 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
#6  0x00007ffff7493751 in PyRun_FileExFlags () from /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
#7  0x00007ffff7493954 in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags () from /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
#8  0x00007ffff748970b in Py_Main () from /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
#9  0x0000555555554c39 in main ()
```

### EDIT

The problem was unrelated to reference counting (I think)

When adding the type to the module I made a copy-pasta mistake.

```
if (PyType_Ready(&HexRingGenType) < 0)
    return NULL;
```

should have been

```
if (PyType_Ready(&HexRangeGenType) < 0)
    return NULL
```

fixing this caused the segfault to go away.

As noted by ShadowRanger in the comments, I am also making mistakes in the reference counting

Comment: You're not establishing proper invariants in your `new`, and/or your `dealloc` isn't respecting them. When `new` completes and returns an object, you must be able to legally `dealloc` the result with no further actions. But `hex` and `center` are `NULL`, while `dealloc` assumes they are non-`NULL`  (by using `Py_DECREF` instead of `Py_XDECREF`). No idea if it's the cause, but mistakes like that indicate you're not paying attention to invariants. Given there are tons of other undescribed types here (e.g. `self->center` is a custom type we have almost no info on), it's pretty hard to answer.

Comment: I'm also skeptical of the terminal case for your `tp_next` method; it looks like it's unconditionally putting new values in `hex` that may or may not mean something after caching a return value, but in the terminal case (when `tp_next` returns `NULL` to indicate end of iteration), that means `self->hex` was `NULL` and becomes something else just before iteration ends (which doesn't make a whole lot of sense).

Comment: Basically, we need a [MCVE], and this is neither a minimal nor complete nor verifiable example. I suspect the process of debugging and minimizing it might point you towards the cause of the bug though.